# Declarar clase desde variable string sin usar EVAL()

Tags: php, poo

Muy buenas tardes, Por motivos de seguridad quiero evitar que la declaración de un objeto esté almacenada en formato texto plano en el sistema de archivo, por lo cual el tradicional método de usar include() o require() o estar incluida en mi archivo de programa NO ES opción. (el contenido de la variable será el resultado de desencriptar un archivo, luego de recibir la llave por sockets desde otro equipo.)

Quisiera saber si se puede declarar una clase cuya definición está almacenada en una variable string (adjunto ejemplo que es funcional) sin usar eval.

```
<?php

// almaceno en la variable $cDefClase la clase a declarar.
$cDefClase = 'class Foo {

  var $bar;

  public function setBar($value) {
    $this->bar = $value;
  }

  public function someFunction($param) {
    echo $param.$this->bar."<br/>";  
  }

} ';

// declaro la clase
eval( $cDefClase );

// Instancio la clase
$foo = new Foo();

// Uso la clase
$foo->setBar("Gustavo");
$foo->someFunction("Hola ");

?>
```

desde ya muchas gracias.

P.D. El objeto en cuestión gestionará los accesos a la Db para transparentar el almacenamiento de columnas encriptadas en la db relacional. Si alguno tiene referencia de trabajos que analicen pros y contras de soluciones que YA se usen y estén probados para resolver esta cuestión agradeceré compartan algun link de referencia. desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: proba un encoder [phpbolt](https://phpbolt.com/how-to-encrypt-php-source-code/) [ioncube](https://www.ioncube.com/php_encoder.php)

Comment: Gracias Alo, voy a googlear phpbolt ioncube 

abrazo